# Since 2013 we hv bin in a rltnshp wth ma girlfrnd n we hv had 2 kids. We hv jst got officially mrrd on 20/3/2022. R our 2 sweet kid also purified now?

Tags: halal-haram

All we r asking to know is weather our two kids we got before we officially got married in our islamic religon r now purified i.e can be treated equally like d ones produced after the two lovers got officially married

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. I strongly suggest you to use a shorter question title (summary of the content) and write in a readable and correct English.

Comment: Write another question. Shorter question and simpler question.